# Почему не работает gdeliteli = list(set(deliteli) & set(deliteli2))

Tags: python

Я написал программу для нахождения наибольшего общего делителя.
Но почему, когда я ввожу числа (9, 27, 81), он выдаёт мне, что наибольший общий делитель 3?
Вот код:

```
numbers = []
delitels = 1
deliteli = []
gdeliteli = []
deliteli2 = []
delimiy = 0
def app():
    global numbers
    global delitels
    global deliteli
    global gdeliteli
    global deliteli2
    global num2
    global delimiy
    try:
        nums = int(input("Сколько чисел: "))
        for number in range(1, nums+1):
            nums2 = int(input(f"Введите число {number}: "))
            numbers.append(nums2)
        numbers.sort()
        for num in numbers:
            num2 = int(num)
            while delitels != num:
                delimiy = 1
                while delimiy < num2:
                    delimiy += 1
                    if num2 % delimiy == 0:
                        break
                num2 /= delimiy
                delitels = delitels * delimiy
                deliteli2 += str(delimiy)
            delitels = 1
            if len(deliteli) != 0:
                gdeliteli = list(set(deliteli) & set(deliteli2))
            else:
                deliteli += deliteli2
            deliteli2 = []
        i = 1
        for x in gdeliteli:
            i *= int(x)
        print(gdeliteli)
        print(f"НОД({numbers})={i}")
    except ValueError:
        print("Неправлиьное значение. Попробуйте ещё раз.")
        app()
app()
```

Подскажите, как сделать адекватное наложение списков.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Может можно просто найти все делители каждого, пересечь и взять максимум:

```py
numbers = [9, 27, 81]
# делители
dividers = [{x for x in range(1, num + 1) if num % x == 0 } for num in numbers]
from functools import reduce
# общие делители
d = reduce((lambda x, y: x & y), dividers)
# НОД
print(max(d))
```

Конструкция `[{x for x in range(1, num + 1) if num % x == 0 } for num in numbers]` - создать `list`, элементами которого будут множества (`{}`), множества строятся так:

- берем очередной `num` из `numbers` (`for num in numbers`)
- организуем цикл по числам от 1 до `num + 1` (`range(1, num + 1)`)
- в множество добавляем те числа, на которые `num` делится без остатка - то есть его делители (`if num % x == 0`)

например для `numbers = [9, 27, 81]` `dividers` будет:

`[{1, 3, 9}, {27, 1, 3, 9}, {1, 3, 9, 81, 27}]`

Comment: Извините, что значит: dividers = [{x for x in range(1, num + 1) if num % x == 0 } for num in numbers]

Comment: @МаксМазур дополнила ответ

Comment: спасибо большое)